# How to convert existing height of UIView for iphone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, iphone-5

Hi I have developed app for iPhone4 now I want to convert the app into iPhone5, I have a UIView named settingsView it is popped up by click of a UIButton. I wanted to know how to adjust the height of the settingsView for iPhone5 .

```
 -(IBAction)settingsButtonChanged:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIImageView *settingsImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settingsViewImage.png"]];
    settingsImage.frame = CGRectMake(25.0, 40.0, 280.0, 370.0);


    settingsView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 280.0, 370.0);
    settingsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [settingsView addSubview:settingsImage];

}
```

Comment: @rptwsthi words like 'iPhone' are *product names*; they are not code. The other things you have highlighted are class names, and not really 'code' in the way they are being used. Formatting them as code inline like this just makes the post harder to read.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Hmm, I'll keep that in my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, you would like to use two storyboards, one for iPhones 3.5" and the other for iPhones 4". By putting this code on your app delegate, you'll be able to have those storyboards working:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0){
            //move to your iphone5 storyboard
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphoneFiveStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            UIViewController *vc =[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

            self.window.rootViewController = vc;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }
        else{
            //move to your iphone4s storyboard
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            UIViewController *vc =[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

            self.window.rootViewController = vc;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }}
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Now you only need to go to: File -> New... -> File -> User Interface -> Storyboard

And name the storyboard "iphoneFiveStoryboard"...

Now you can remake all the storyboard with 4" views!

Hope you understood, I tried to explain the best I could...

Answer (score 4):

If you use the new autolayout system, you can set constraints that will automatically adjust your view's layout to take advantage of the screen size. For example, if you have several elements near the top of the view, a table in the middle, and some buttons near the bottom,  you can add constraints that:

- keep the top elements a fixed distance from the top of the view
- keep the spacing between top elements fixed
- keep the bottom buttons a fixed distance from the bottom of the view
- adjust the table's height so that the table grows on a larger screen and shrinks on a smaller one

You can do the math and make the adjustments yourself, but the whole point of the autolayout system is that you don't have to bother -- let the view do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

use `self.view.frame.size.height`, you may have to divide this by something to match your ratio of 320:280 that I noticed for width

```
-(IBAction)settingsButtonChanged:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIImageView *settingsImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settingsViewImage.png"]];
    settingsImage.frame = CGRectMake(25.0, 40.0, 280.0, self.view.frame.size.height);
    settingsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [settingsView addSubview:settingsImage];

}
```

Comment: *Note, if you are not in the main ViewController look into the bounds of the devices frame or hard-coding in values after detecting the device ID

Answer (score 2):

You have to check whether the app running on `iPhone 4` or `iPhone 5` below code lines may help you:-

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
        {
            // code for 4-inch screen
            //for eg:-
            [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
-(IBAction)settingsButtonChanged:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIImageView *settingsImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settingsViewImage.png"]];
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    int height = 0;
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
        // Height for iPhone 5 screen
        height = 370+ 88; // it may be your desired height
    } else {
        // Height for iPhone 4 screen
       height = 370;
    }
    settingsImage.frame = CGRectMake(25.0, 40.0, 280.0, height);
    settingsView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 280.0, height);
    settingsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [settingsView addSubview:settingsImage];

}
```